# Почему не выполняется POST node.js?

Tags: node.js, api, express, amazon

Есть небольшое тестовое приложение на node.js с фреймоворком express.js.

Пытаюсь потестировать **API Amazon Moments** https://developer.amazon.com/docs/moments/rewards-...

При попытке сделать **POST** запрос, получаю в ответ вот это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стартовый **index.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var amaz = require('./amazon.js');
var app = express();
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 80;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(PORT,function(){
  console.log('server successfully started on port ' + PORT);
  amaz;
});
```

**amazon.js:**

```
const https = require('http')

const data = JSON.stringify({
  "x-api-key": "12345",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "appId": "DEMO1",
  "momentId": "GAME_COMPLETE",
  "deviceType": 'Android ',
  'campaignId ': "DEMOCAMP1",
  "rewardGroupId": "amz1yprime"
})

const options = {
  url: 'https://dnxr7vm27d.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/GetRewardInfo',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'x-api-key': 'kE2xi2OgUa7jfijmsd0jQ74aJntJwUEW2EU8LUsi'
  }
}

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)

  module.exports = res.on('data', (d) => {
    console.log(d);
  })
})

req.on('error', (error) => {
  console.error(error.message)
})

req.write(data)
req.end()
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

У вас роут принимает get запрос.
замените

```js
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});
```

на

```js
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});
```

Comment: ну или в файле amazon.js строку method: 'POST', поменять на method: 'GET' что по моему будет логичней)

Comment: Так-то заработало, но не так, как нужно :)
Теперь ответ:
statusCode: 200
Hello World!

Comment: так его отправляет amazon.js

Answer (score 0):

Решил переделать код под модуль Request, не используя модуль Http:

```
const request = require('request')

var options = {
  url: 'https://dnxr7vm27d.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/GetRewardInfo',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'x-api-key': 'kE2xi2OgUa7jfijmsd0jQ74aJntJwUEW2EU8LUsi'
  },
  body: {
    'appId': 'DEMO1',
    'momentId':'GAME_COMPLETE',
    'deviceType' : 'Android',
    'campaignId' : 'DEMOCAMP1',
    'rewardGroupId': 'amz1yprime'
  },
  json: true // sets body to JSON representation of value 
};

request.post(options, (err, httpResponse, body) => {
  if (err) console.error(err);
  // httpResponse contains the full response object, httpResponse.statusCode etc
  else console.log(body);
})
```

Все заработало, как нужно